# Is the minimum character edit limit useful?

Tags: discussion, editing

I sometimes see a clear, well-framed question with one tiny but glaring error, for example "have" instead of "had" or "loosen" instead of "looser". It's a good question, but a good answer is going to have to compete with a lot of nit picking. I can't just fix the error because of the minimum five character limit.

I have seen posts where somebody has fixed the glaring error and made other subtle changes in order to exceed the five character limit. This is well-meaning but must be very confusing for newcomers.

What purposes do the five character limit serve? Is it really beneficial to the site?

[test]

Comment: You only need 2,000 rep to have your edits applied immediately and the 6 character limitation goes away. I try not to make trivial edits even though I have the rep to do so (corrections of typos in answers are the exception). Usually, I find that the title of a question can almost always be made more specific, or the tags improved, or some formatting applied.

Comment: I removed 2 letters and added 7. StackExchange reports "added 9 characters in body"

Comment: @TRomano: Interesting... I didn't know that the 6-character limit goes away when you reach 2000 rep: in that context, the 6-character limit seems more sensible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's six characters, and yes, it's useful. You have stuff to read for the rest of the day:

- [How to overcome "Edits must be at least 6 characters"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81520/how-to-overcome-edits-must-be-at-least-6-characters)
- [Legitimate edits of less than 6 characters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149771/legitimate-edits-of-less-than-6-characters)
- [Minimum 6 character edit is not a practical rule](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216332/minimum-6-character-edit-is-not-a-practical-rule)
- [Minimum number of characters to change is problematic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112246/minimum-number-of-characters-to-change-is-problematic)
- [How can users convince SE that the 6 character minimum edit requirement is counterproductive?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257479/how-can-users-convince-se-that-the-6-character-minimum-edit-requirement-is-count)

And a thousand others. Per Shog's answer to [Why are trivial edits discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74430/why-are-trivial-edits-discouraged/214892#214892):

> The Stack Exchange model for editing is a hybrid of these two approaches. While it falls somewhat closer to the wiki model than the forum model, it deviates from the latter in a few key areas:
>
> Edits made by the same editor in a short period of time are collapsed: no matter how many times a post is edited within a 5-minute window, only one revision is stored (as long as only one editor is involved). This largely eliminates the need for a "minor edit" feature.
>
> Tools for comparing revisions are much more limited: only revisions directly adjacent in the chronology can be compared.
>
> Outside of Community Wiki posts, an original author is always maintained and clearly identified even if substantial changes have been made by other editors since the post was created.
>
> Together, this hybrid system allows for a much simpler, much easier-to-read, easier-to-navigate user interface. However, this comes at a cost: trivial one-off edits must be discouraged in favor of more comprehensive edits.
>
> If merely maintaining a simple UI were the only concern, it might be worthwhile to consider an optional "expert" mode that allowed minor edits at the cost of a more involved UI. However, there's a much bigger concern...

This is deep into the design of the system. Your edit *must* be non-trivial. This has already been discussed enough, and you can find out more by searching in meta.SE or meta.SO.

You can instead

- Leave a comment pointing out the error
- Leaving the post for the higher-rep users to edit
- Ping someone in chat and ask them to edit
- Make your edit more **substantial**. I rarely edit less than 6 characters while being a privileged user myself.

I hope this clears things up.

Comment: If the error is very distracting, one could also flag it for moderator attention. Incidentally, I think there are times when minor edits **are** substantial edits, like when an O.P. misspells the word being asked about in the title of the question. For example, suppose someone is asking about the expression _a frog in my throat_, and their title says, _Meaning of ‘from in my throat’_. (Character counts aren't always a indicator of the substance of the edit. It may be an imperfect system, but it works – it prevents newer users from flooding the system with trivial edits.)